# How to pass functions into boost::geometry::index::satisfies() without a lambda expression

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, parameter-passing, c++03

So I am using Boost's R-tree for an optimized spatial search. The parameters of the query is a search center and a radius, so I would be using my own function to see if the distance between a given point in the rtree and the given search center is less than the given distance. This is where a lambda expression would be perfect, as most of the examples I've seen for the satisfies() function use a lambda expression. Unfortunately, we are still using C++03 so lambdas are out of the question.

I was able to pass in my own function, but I couldn't figure out how to pass any paramters along with it, just the value in the R-tree that it was iterating over. I ended up using a weird workaround with static member variables that just feels like a very wrong way to do this.

```
bool inRange(Location const& loc)
{
   return boost::geometry::distance(loc, RTree::searchCenter) < RTree::searchRadius;
}

vector<Location> RTree::query(Location const& loc, double const& sr)
{
   searchCenter = loc; // static member variable
   searchRadius = sr; // static member variable

   vector<Location> ret;

   rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::satisfies(inRange), back_inserter(ret));

   return ret;
}
```

This looks and feels incredible jenky to me. How can I make it look something like this?

```
bool inRange(Location const& loc1, Location const& loc2, double const& sr)
{
   return boost::geometry::distance(loc1, loc2) < sr;
}

vector<Location> RTree::query(Location const& loc, double const& sr)
{
   vector<Location> ret;

   rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::satisfies(inRange(loc,sr)), back_inserter(ret));

   return ret;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use `boost::bind` instead or simulate lambda with a custom class.

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you!

Comment: @CyrusFarsoudi `satisfies` is not a spatial predicate so spatial qualities of the rtree are not used in your example. In other words its like checking all Locations stored in a vector. You have to pass e.g. `intersects(rect_covering_circle) && satisfies(...)`. I also propose to replace `distance()` with `comparable_distance()` which is faster and in cartesian is squared distance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this was my solution

```
bool RTree::inRange(Location const& loc1, Location const& loc2, double const& sr)
{
   return boost::geometry::distance(loc1, loc2) < sr;
}

vector<Location> RTree::query(Location const& loc, double const& sr)
{
   vector<Location> ret;

   rtree.query(boost::geometry::index::satisfies(boost::bind(&RTree::inRange, this, _1, loc, sr), back_inserter(ret));

   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Recommend against using `#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS`